# windows 10 Native Build error - Native-image building on Windows currently only supports target architecture: AMD64 (x86 unsupported)

Tags: gluon, gluon-desktop

I'm testing out a new project, and trying to use Gluon for this.
ATM I am building on windows 10 with AMD Ryzen 7.

Following the instructions from: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_windows

When I attempt to build:**mvn gluonfx:build** it fails with:

```
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.9:compile (default-cli) @ gluon-singleviewproject-jdk17 ---
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:32 PST 2021][INFO] ==================== COMPILE TASK ====================
             _______  ___      __   __  _______  __    _
            |       ||   |    |  | |  ||       ||  |  | |
            |    ___||   |    |  | |  ||   _   ||   |_| |
            |   | __ |   |    |  |_|  ||  | |  ||       |
            |   ||  ||   |___ |       ||  |_|  ||  _    |
            |   |_| ||       ||       ||       || | |   |
            |_______||_______||_______||_______||_|  |__|
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:33 PST 2021][INFO] We will now compile your code for x86_64-microsoft-windows. This may take some time.

    Access to the latest docs, tips and tricks and more info on
    how to get support? Register your usage of Gluon Substrate now at

    https://gluonhq.com/activate



[Tue Nov 16 13:14:34 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Ignoring server-mode native-image argument --no-server.
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:36 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] [com.gluonapplication.gluonapplication:29680]    classlist:   1,238.84 ms,  0.96 GB
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] [com.gluonapplication.gluonapplication:29680]        setup:     709.11 ms,  0.96 GB
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Error: Native-image building on Windows currently only supports target architecture: AMD64 (x86 unsupported)
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Error: To prevent native-toolchain checking provide command-line option -H:-CheckToolchain
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Native-image building on Windows currently only supports target architecture: AMD64 (x86 unsupported)
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] To prevent native-toolchain checking provide command-line option -H:-CheckToolchain
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:139)
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.codegen.CCompilerInvoker.addSkipCheckingInfo(CCompilerInvoker.java:103)
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.codegen.CCompilerInvoker.verifyCompiler(CCompilerInvoker.java:94)
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:884)
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:530)
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:491)
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:380)
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:543)
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:119)
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:573)
[Tue Nov 16 13:14:37 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] [com.gluonapplication.gluonapplication:29680]      [total]:   1,978.21 ms,  0.96 GB
```

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gluonapplication</groupId>
    <artifactId>gluon-singleviewproject-jdk17</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Gluon-SingleViewProject-jdk17</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>17.0.1</javafx.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.13</attach.version>
        <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.9</gluonfx.plugin.version>
        <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.plugin.version>
        <mainClassName>com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication</mainClassName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>host</target>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

This is is basically hellofxml, any thoughts or pointers on debugging this greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a 32 bits system? Only 64 bits OSes are supported.

Comment: ryzen 7 is 64 bit...but..I wonder if I have a 32 bit of something installed! which is causing this.

Comment: Can you run your app (`mvn javafx:run`) adding  `System.out.println(“Arch: “ + System.getProperty("os.arch"));`?

Comment: checking the download folder, everything downloaded: java 17, javafx, are both x64.  Any thoughts on any special command I can run to verify libs/components?  (ps this is windows home, suspect that should not matter).

Comment: Progress! (I was using the x86 Native cmd prompt, not x86_64 (Cross Tools Command Prompt)...now running into different in issue will debug further (Error parsing configuration file...reflect-config.json).

Comment: Moved new issue to new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007754/mvn-gluonrunagent-failure-unknown-attribute-queryalldeclaredmethods-in-d

Comment: I'm having the same problem building the image in docker, and I'm using the x86_x64 cross :(. @JoséPereda do you have an idea? Thanks

Comment: @Ikaro Do you have the exact same error? Else can you post a new question with your stacktrace?