# mvn gluon:runagent failure - Unknown Attribute 'queryAllDeclaredMethods' .. in definition of class ..HelloController

Tags: gluon, gluon-desktop

trying to get my first native build working.

(using Windows 10, jdk 17, javafx17, gluon 1.0.9, gluon graalvm (graalvm-svm-windows-gluon-21.2.0-dev.zip))

I am able to run **mvn gluonfx:run**
(and click on the 1 button I have in my test UI)

However when I run: **mvn gluonfx:runagent**, I get:

```
    [Wed Nov 17 08:10:41 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Error: Error parsing reflection configuration in file:/C:/devel/repos/Gluon-SingleViewProject-jdk17/target/classes/META-INF%5cnative-image%5creflect-config.json:
[Wed Nov 17 08:10:41 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Unknown attribute 'queryAllDeclaredMethods' (supported attributes: allDeclaredConstructors, allPublicConstructors, allDeclaredMethods, allPublicMethods, allDeclaredFields, allPublicFields, methods, fields) in defintion of class com.gluonapplication.HelloController
[Wed Nov 17 08:10:41 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Verify that the configuration matches the schema described in the -H:PrintFlags=+ output for option ReflectionConfigurationResources.
[Wed Nov 17 08:10:41 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Error parsing reflection configuration in file:/C:/devel/repos/Gluon-SingleViewProject-jdk17/target/classes/META-INF%5cnative-image%5creflect-config.json:
[Wed Nov 17 08:10:41 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Unknown attribute 'queryAllDeclaredMethods' (supported attributes: allDeclaredConstructors, allPublicConstructors, allDeclaredMethods, allPublicMethods, allDeclaredFields, allPublicFields, methods, fields) in defintion of class com.gluonapplication.HelloController
[Wed Nov 17 08:10:41 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Verify that the configuration matches the schema described in the -H:PrintFlags=+ output for option ReflectionConfigurationResources.
```

The helloController, simply consists of 1 method atm:

```
public class HelloController {
    public void pressButton(ActionEvent ae){
        System.out.println("hello, source pressed: " + ae.getSource());
    }    
}
```

Any suggestions/tips greatly appreciated...(based on the error above..looks like build process is may be calling an unsupported method for jdk 17?)

Comment: Follow https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_windows, use the recommended GraalVM version

Comment: sorry updated initial question, but I believe I am doing that: I have graalvm: graalvm-svm-windows-gluon-21.2.0-dev.zip installed.  GRAALVM_HOME=C:\devel\graal\graalvm-svm-windows-gluon-21.2.0-dev

Comment: Gluon”s build of GraalVM is based on JDK 11. You need to use that too to run `runagent` instead of JDK 17 (setting `JAVA_HOME`` or adding the `executable`  option to the JavaFX plugin)

Comment: hrm, ok to verify/qa: to use gluon java 11 must be used? are there any plans to support jdk 17 in near future? (I think i am actualy using a few features post jdk-11 atm), thanx.

Comment: 17 is supported too, but for that you need GraalVM based on JDK 17, you can use their latest release.

Comment: Sorry Jose I'm confused, are you saying that I do not need to use the Gluon GraalVM?, when you say 'you can use their latest release', whom are you referring to? (Graalvm.org?), in this case I would just point change my GRAALVM_HOME to point to that installation?

Comment: Yes, Gluon’s build is only based on JDK 11. You can find GraalVM releases based on JDK 17 on GraalVM‘s repository

Comment: Excellent, ty, I will give that a shot today :)

Comment: progress(using: graalvm-ce-java17-21.3.0) I was able to runagent, but build is now failing, with many..errors of this nature: [INFO] [SUB] com.gluonapplication.gluonapplication.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol KeyPairGenerator_00024RSA_generateCKeyPair  thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce it. Filed: https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues/1045. It has an easy fix, but it will need a new release of the plugin.

Comment: sweet, thanx for the fast repro, will keep an eye on that issue.

Comment: You can test it now, using the plugin with version  1.0.10-SNAPSHOT, but you need to add  `<pluginsRepository/>`  to the pom with url: http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/